# Custom Rule Action in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-addin

How to create my own custom action in Microsoft Outlook Rules?

In Outlook, when creating a rule in the Rules wizard, we set first the conditions and then set the actions that we choose from a list of predefined actions. Is there a way to add my own action to the existing actions programmatically?

I also see an action called custom action, when i click it it opens up a small window with an empty combobox, can i add my custom action there, and how?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to implement a custom action using pure .NET code. You have create a native DLL. But do you really need it? I assure you, that implementing and supporting the custom action is a pretty tricky challenge.

I suggest you to create a VBA script and use "run a script" Rule Wizard action instead.

Comment: By the way, there are no custom actions in Outlook 2013 any more...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a bunch of documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226710(v=office.12).aspx) on how to create custom actions for Outlook 2007.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but they don't create a custom Action there. Would like to know if i can create a custom action (RuleAction) to be added to the Rules Actions