# Set default outlook send address based on TO field

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is there a way to have outlook pick the right email address based on the TO or CC fields?

For example, if I am sending an email to domain1.com, use account1@domain2.com, else ...

I am open to writing VBA to making this work, but I want to be automatic, not something that I have to remember to do (that is the whole issue to begin with).

So as a two parter:

1. Is there a way to get VBA to run automatically when composing an email like this?
2. Is there support in VBA for changing the the FROM account?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I think it's `application_itemsend` event that you'll need to use. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx). You could do something like "on send, if to field is X, then from field = Y"

Comment: @Raystafarian is there an event that fires when the TO field changes?

Comment: Yes, the mail items `mailitem.recipient` and `mailitem.recipients` [this is the link to office support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211006(v=office.11).aspx). Also, of course is the [mailitem.sender object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869056(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: @Raystafarian Where is the event?

Comment: the event would be `itemadd` or `itemchange`. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609(v=office.15).aspx). also this is a simplified version, but relevant [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110218/outlook-2010-vba-change-properties-on-a-newly-from-exchange-synced-appointment)

Comment: Any luck? I can't help write because I don't have outlook on this machine.

Comment: See if this helps (it's *quite* close to what you want, but will only adjust when you click the send button, but hopefully the code will give you what you need to hack it to get it to work) http://superuser.com/questions/740017/when-using-multiple-accounts-how-to-ensure-emails-are-sent-from-the-correct-acc